# What should we be aware of when moving windows servers to another domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, migration, active-directory

We have a bunch of (virtual vmware) windows servers (2003 and 2008) that our hosting provider wants to move to a new AD domain. They also want to rename the servers (just for the sake of introducing a new naming convention). 
The hosting provider is in charge of maintaining the servers, while we are in charge of making sure that all our business applications are working.
Our business applications include custom developed .net applications using such things as SQLServer 2008, TFS 2010, asp.net, some legacy COM+ apps, etc.

To be honest I don't feel too convinced that this migration will be as painless as the hosting provider wants to make it sound. I would greatly appreciate any input on what we should be aware of when discussing the practicalities involved in the migration with the hosting provider.

Thanks in advance.

Klaus

Comment: What do you mean they want to move them to a new domain? Can you provide more details? Are you referring to a DNS domain or an AD domain? Why would they want to rename the servers?

Comment: @joeqwerty they want to move them to a new AD domain. And they want to rename the servers just for the sake of a new naming convention they want to introduce.

Comment: They are hosting your own stuff in their domain? It's a shared domain? Seems like a weird scenario for a hosting company.

Comment: @mfinni, yeah I'm not saying that it's not a weird setup. They are hosting things in their own domain. The thing is that the hosting company and my current company were once the same company, but they split up years back.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot I imagine. You will probably get orphaned guids in the filesystem permissions. Just be sure none of them are domain controllers or have roles in AD; you will need to reassign those roles and gracefully remove the server if this is the case.

You may have software using permissions from the old domain; sql server may have database permissions based on users from the old domain, so be careful here.

Also services that run on the server may run with a useraccount from the old AD domain.

(basically permissions permissions permissions)